# Is the order of the rows returned by the TABLE function guaranteed to be identical to the order in which the elements of the VARRAY are stored?

Tags: oracle, collections, oracle12c

I am executing a delete statement using bind variables of type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "VAR_ARR" AS
    VARRAY ( 5000 ) OF VARCHAR2(20)
```

The delete statement looks as follows:

```
DELETE FROM ins_test
WHERE
    ( id,
    name ) IN (
        SELECT
            t1.id,
            t2.name
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    column_value id,
                    ROWNUM r
                FROM
                    TABLE (:1 )
            ) t1
            FULL JOIN (
                SELECT
                    column_value name,
                    ROWNUM r
                FROM
                    TABLE (:2 )
            ) t2 ON t1.r = t2.r
    )
```

The statement relies upon the `TABLE` functions to return the elements in the same order as they are stored in the `VARRAY`. Is the order of the rows returned by the TABLE function guaranteed to be identical to the order in which the elements of the VARRAY are stored?

It has been discussed in e.g. [How do I get the index of VARRAY items after converting to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559647/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-varray-items-after-converting-to-a-table), but I cannot find any conclusive information.

Comment: And what does it matter ? In the case of DELETE, this order does not matter. The database will delete records in the order in which it will be convenient to the database, not for you, depending, for example, on whether the table has partitions or not, whether there is an index on this column or not, which method of access to the table will be chosen by the optimizer ( full table scan, index scan, hash join, sort join etc.) and many many other criteria on which we have no influence at all.

Comment: @krokodilko it matters because the where clause must be correct; the first id must be combined with the first name, the second id with the second name and so on. Of course I do not care in which order the rows are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for VARRAY it is, see [Varrays (Variable-Size Arrays)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-E932FC04-C7AD-4562-9555-8BA05446C0B8)

> When you store and retrieve a varray from the database, its indexes and element order remain stable.

Just a note, for [Nested Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-5ADB7EE2-71F6-4172-ACD8-FFDCF2787A37) you have the opposite:

> The indexes and row order of a nested table might not remain stable as you store and retrieve the nested table from the database.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Are you sure retrieving includes the TABLE function? Not only procedural retrieval element by element?

Comment: I assume whenever you use `select ... from ...` then the order is never determined unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Yes, I am leaning towards that the answer is no. That there is no guarantee.

Comment: @user2672165 - There has been discussion of this on OTN (community.oracle.com) just recently. The prevailing opinion is that (1) the TABLE operator may indeed disturb the order at least in some cases, even if in "simple" test cases it does not; (2) the Oracle documentation does not state anywhere that the order of elements will be preserved when going through the TABLE operator (even if it doesn't say the opposite either, and no one is aware of a single specific example when the order is disturbed). https://community.oracle.com/thread/4119842